# Take `self` without 'def __init__' an instance in Django

Tags: django

'Generic view class' in Django puzzles me very much.
for instance:

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs.get('username')
        if username is None:
            raise Http404
        return get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=username, is_active=True)
```

Without the procedure of getting instantiated, it works as well.

What I can understand is:

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_object(self):
        username = self.kwargs.get('username')
        if username is None:
            raise Http404
        return get_object_or_404(User, username__iexact=username, is_active=True)
```

What's the mechanism behind it?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking... are you asking how [`as_view`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/base.py#L50) works?

Comment: the first class works without def  `__init__`

Comment: Thats just basic inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the fundamental principle of inheritance:

for your reference:

[9. Classes — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables)

```
class Mapping:
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.items_list = []
        self.__update(iterable)

    def update(self, iterable):
        for item in iterable:
            self.items_list.append(item)

    __update = update   # private copy of original update() method

class MappingSubclass(Mapping):

    def update(self, keys, values):
        # provides new signature for update()
        # but does not break __init__()
        for item in zip(keys, values):
            self.items_list.append(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Python3` `super` method behaves a bit more magically. It automatically figures out the parent of the class and implicitly passes the `self` as well. It has nothing to do specifically with Django itself. It's been done so to reduce the code redundancy. It is pretty irritating to be forced to change all `super` calls when changing the name of the class.

```
# Python2

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

# Python 3

class B(A):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now as far as Django generic views are concerned, there is an `as_view` class method that creates a callable instance of the View, which delegates the call to `dispatch` method.

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The `__init__` method named `constructor` call automatically when you instantiated Class. Here As you inherit `DetailView` so super() call takes all `__init__` functionality from DetailView.

```
class ProfileDetailView(DetailView): # here DetailView is inherited
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs) # Own class(ProfileDetailView)'s __init__
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) # it takes DetailView's __init__ behabiour
```

and it is not `ProfileDetailView` own so 2nd `__init__` avoid `self`.